# Equivalent data types of C++ in C#

Tags: c#, mfc, casting, types, pinvoke

I'm trying to use a MFC Dll in my C# app. It basically is a proxy for easier connection with a hardware device.
 I'm writing a wrapper class using P/Invoke to be able to use the methods defined in the dll.

- I'm fairly new to P/Invoke stuff. It this going to work? I can't test it very often because I have not the hardware available to test on my dev machine.
- Could you refer me to a page with equivalent data types of C++ in C#? What type should I use when the variable has a * next to it? like
  `double *`, `ULONG *`, `int *`

---

```
ULONG WINAPI PCXUS_Open(ULONG *hPCXUS, int boot)   
ULONG WINAPI PCXUS_WRITE( ULONG hPCXUS, int Board, int Test, int Unit, 
LPCSTR strParam, double *dblValue, double dblArrayValue1[MAX_ROW], 
double dblArrayValue2[MAX_ROW], LPSTR StrValue, int *Clipped)
```

And lastly, how should I define variables with brackets in their definitions? Like:
`double dblArrayValue1[MAX_ROW]`, `double dblArrayValue1[MAX_ROW]`

UPDATE: Here's the definition for the second method:

```
Arguments:
hPCXUS         //Your access number (see PCXUS_Open function)
Board          //Board number (0 to N)
Test           //Test number (0 to 7) (only for USPC with MUX extension)
Unit           //0 = µs ; 1 = mm ; 2 = inch
StrParam       //Pointer to parameter name ( see the list )
DblValue       //Pointer to parameter value
DblArrayValue1 //Parameter data array 1
DblArrayValue2 //Parameter data array 2
StrValue       //ASCII parameter value
Clipped        //Pointer to clip information
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, odds are decent that you can pinvoke these functions.  They look like regular C functions, not instance methods of a C++ class.  ULONG is uint in C#, double is plain double.  The * means that a pointer to the value is passed.  It is ambiguous though, it could either be an argument that's passed by reference (ref or out keyword in C#) or it could be an array.

The first function definitely passes its 1st argument as "out uint" in C#, it returns a handle value.

The second function is tougher.  There's no decent guess whether *dblValue* is an array or passed by reference, its name is lousy.  Start your guess at "ref double", you have to look in the C++ code to be sure.  Same problem with strParam, it should be "string" if its value is passed in, StringBuilder if a value is returned.  The dblArrayValue arguments are definitely arrays, double[] in C#.

Comment: Thanks. This helps me alot. I have updated my question. could you please take a look at arguments and shed some lights on it for me? Plus: is this the correct implementation of the first function? `public static extern UInt32 PCXUS_Open(ref UInt32 hPCXUS, int boot);`

Comment: My answer is still accurate.  Use out.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, that should work.

For C# data types:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s1ax56ch(v=VS.100).aspx

For C# pointers:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y31yhkeb(v=VS.100).aspx

An array of doubles is `double[]` in C#.

Comment: Thank you. How should I define MAX_ROW? is it a predefined constant in the Dll?

Comment: Someone may be able to correct me on this, but I don't believe there's a way to pull constants out of the DLL like that.  It's safe to declare the return type as `double[]` and then either redeclare the constant (probably not preferable) or create a function that will output the MAX_ROW value at runtime when you're actually iterating.

Comment: Guess I'll go with dependency walker and just redefine it in my c# wrapper.

Answer (score 0):

I've been working with C++ bere years... Some of the most common data types in C++ are the same in C# as in C++.

- (C++)[int]    ==  C# [int].
- (C++)[char]   ==  C# [char].
- (C++)[float]  ==  C# [float].
- (C++)[double] ==  C# [double].
- (C++)[bool]   ==  C# [bool].
- (C++)[void]   ==  C# [void].

It's important to note that C# has some data types that C++ doesn't have, such as string and decimal.